# How to obtain string date from xml and convert in a correct format in ax?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am trying to obtain a date from an XML file that is in this format:

> 2016-10-27

however, the field I am trying to put it in is in this format:

> mm/dd/yyyy

is there a code for this in dynamics ax 2012? I tried str2date but it doesn't output anything.

SOLVED: ***Just to let you guys know***  even though you are obtaining a string that has a format like mine 2016-10-27 AX automatically formats it to the default format to 10/27/2016 just input the sequence correctly. (**THIS IS NOT PART OF THE ANSWER I AM JUST EXPLAINING MY FINDINGS**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use str2date(string _date, int _sequence). Specify the related format in sequence. Your desired format will be 213

Comment: Hi sir. Sorry but my posts was incorrect, it is str2date is what I've already tried. Again, it doesn't work. Already corrected my post.

Comment: In your case the sequence would be 321 (YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: Hi sir just misunderstood the function, works now thank you.

Comment: Yes, Aliaassandr is correct. You will need to use str2date(xmlDate, 321). The output will be a date object. AX will automatically convert the target date format to mm/dd/yyyy if both the source and target are of type Date